# how to upload an image in opencv-visualstudio2010 x64 win7.. 

Tags: opencv, upload, image

I have written a program to open a photo named "fruits.jpg" with opencv.

When I run this code, I get an empty window as a result, instead of a window with the picture that I'm trying to display.

The code is as follows:

```
911228.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv\cvaux.h"
#include "opencv\cxcore.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main(int argc, const char** argv[])
{
    IplImage* img =0;
    img= cvLoadImage( "D:\open\fruits.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow("Example2.1",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Example2.1",img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example2.1");
    return 0;
}
```

- I have tried to set path, library directories etc...
- Secondly I'm not getting the meaning of argv[]... what is argv[]?
- Should I tell the code how many rows and columns I have in my original picture...

I am a newbie to visual studio and opencv, please help.

Answer (score 4):

1) argc and argv[] have nothing to do with opencv, its the basic signature of a main function in C.
argc - command line argument count
argv[] - array of string (char*) command line argument

2) you have toם many imports that do the same

```
  #include <cv.h>
  #include <highgui.h>
```

these are the only imports you need.

3) the problem probably lies within the path you're trying to load, try to do it as following

```
      img= cvLoadImage( "D:\\open\\fruits.jpg");
```

if that does not work, put the file in the project folder (the folder with the .vcproj file in it) and the do

```
      img= cvLoadImage( "fruits.jpg");
```

Comment: thanks so much ...it worked for me img= cvLoadImage( "D:\\open\\fruits.jpg"); thanks again.. god bless you...BOAZ JAN...
(numair)